# A blank black page blinks before moving to main view from Launch screen storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, launch-screen

I have a video playing when the app loads and a screen shot of first frame of that video in launch screen so that the transition from launch screen to main view looks smooth and uninterrupted. But I'm getting a blank screen that blinks for a fraction of a second before moving to main view.

I'm using `MPMoviePlayerController` to play the video in full screen in `MainViewController` and the screenshot in `launscreen.storyboard`.

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your MPMoviePlayerController.m to viewDidLoad method, just after

[super viewDidLoad];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

May this help you,